# How to modify immutable objects passed as **arguments in functions with Python3 the elegant way?

Tags: python-3.x, immutability

I am not sure what the problem is here, so I don't really know how I should call the subject for that question. Please offer a better subject if you know.

The code below is a extrem simplified example of the original one. But it reproduce the problem very nice. After the call of `test()` `foo` should be `sieben`.

I think I didn't know some special things about scopes of variables in Python. This might be a very good problem to learn more about that. But I don't know on which Python topic I should focus here to find a solution for my own.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def test(handlerFunction, **handlerArgs):
    handlerFunction(**handlerArgs)

def myhandler(dat):
    print('dat={}'.format(dat))
    dat = 'sieben'
    print('dat={}'.format(dat))

foo = 'foo'
test(myhandler, dat=foo)
print('foo={}'.format(foo))
```

Of course I could make `foo` a `global` variable. But that is not the goal. The goal is to carry this variable inside and through sub-functions of different levels and bring the result back. In the original code I use some more complexe data structures with `**handlerArgs`.

A solution could be to use a `list()` as an mutable object holding the immutable one. But is this really *elegant* or *pythonic*?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def test(handlerFunction, **handlerArgs):
    handlerFunction(**handlerArgs)

def myhandler(dat):
    print('dat={}'.format(dat))
    # MODIFIED LINE
    dat[0] = 'sieben'
    print('dat={}'.format(dat))

# MODIFIED LINE
foo = ['foo']
test(myhandler, dat=foo)
print('foo={}'.format(foo))
```

Comment: Would the down-voter please comment on the downvote. I am willed to learn. That is why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `**` syntax has nothing to do with this. `dat` is local to `myhandler`, and assigning it doesn't change the global variable with the same name. If you want to change the module variable from inside the function, declare the variable as `global` at the beginning of the function body:

```
def myhandler(): # you don't need to pass dat as argument
    global dat
    print('dat={}'.format(dat))
    dat = 'sieben'
    print('dat={}'.format(dat))
```

Here's a relevant portion from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names):

> If a name binding operation occurs anywhere within a code block, all uses of the name within the block are treated as references to the current block. This can lead to errors when a name is used within a block before it is bound. This rule is subtle. Python lacks declarations and allows name binding operations to occur anywhere within a code block. The local variables of a code block can be determined by scanning the entire text of the block for name binding operations.
>
> If the `global` statement occurs within a block, all uses of the name specified in the statement refer to the binding of that name in the top-level namespace. Names are resolved in the top-level namespace by searching the global namespace, i.e. the namespace of the module containing the code block, and the builtins namespace, the namespace of the module `builtins`. The global namespace is searched first. If the name is not found there, the builtins namespace is searched. The `global` statement must precede all uses of the name.

---

After your edit the question reads as: "how do I mutate an immutable object?"

Well, I think you've guessed it: you don't. Using a mutable object in this manner seems reasonable to me.